# changing some parts of location.href using js without redirecting the browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery

hi here is the problem: my url is like this
`http://somesite.com?theSearch=someword&a=b&c=d`

on this page search results are displayed and on this page i have put the functionality of ajax search i.e. the results are updated without the page reload but the problem is if the user clicks on any link on the page and then presses the back button he results on the page page with the search results of "someword" not the new word typed (i mean the word for which the ajax results were updated) the client complains it and i need to fix it anyone have a solution?

i am using jQuery

Comment: this would do the trick http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/history.html , but its not available on much browsers at the moment (chrome comes to mind)

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the location.href without a new load. What you can do is set the hash.

Every time you make a search change the hash

```
function doSearch(searchword) {
    location.hash = searchword;
    //your search code
}
```

Now the hash will refer to the latest search. And then add this code to "override" the get parameter `?theSearch=`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if(location.hash.length>0) {
        doSearch(location.hash);
    }
});
```

Its not a nice solution since you will load 2 search results, but it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Sammy](http://code.quirkey.com/sammy/). It utilizes the URL hash (#) so you can create single page applications that still respond to the back button in your browser, just like facebook. And it runs on jQuery.

Comment: thankx buddy but it works with the "hash" part of the url and i need to change a part b/w url i can't re-factor the code becus i am near the deadline :( thanks for your help anyway

Comment: @user: You can't do what you want without changing the hash (or by changing the main part of the URL).